# FIFO queue table for multiple workers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking, queue

I was attempting to answer the following stackoverflow question:

- [What SQL Server 2005/2008 locking approach should I use to process individual table rows in multiple server application instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333527/what-sql-server-2005-2008-locking-approach-should-i-use-to-process-individual-ta/11333725)

After posting a somewhat naive answer, I figured I'd put my money where my mouth was and actually *test* the scenario I was suggesting, to be sure I wasn't sending the OP off on a wild goose chase. Well, it's turned out to be much harder than I thought (no surprise there to anyone, I'm sure).

Here's what I've tried and thought about:

- First I tried a TOP 1 UPDATE with an ORDER BY inside a derived table, using `ROWLOCK, READPAST`. This yielded deadlocks and also processed items out of order. It must be as close to FIFO as possible, barring errors that require attempting to process the same row more than once.
- I then tried selecting the desired next QueueID into a variable, using various combinations of `READPAST`, `UPDLOCK`, `HOLDLOCK`, and `ROWLOCK` to exclusively preserve the row for update by that session. All of the variations I tried suffered from the same issues as before as well as, for certain combinations with `READPAST`, complaining:

  > You can only specify the READPAST lock in the READ COMMITTED or REPEATABLE READ isolation levels.

  This was confusing because it *was* READ COMMITTED. I have run into this before and it is frustrating.
- Since I started writing this question, Remus Rusani posted a new answer to the question. I read his linked article and see that he is using destructive reads, since he said in his answer that it "is not realistically possible to hold on to locks for the duration of the web calls." After reading what his article says regarding hot spots and pages requiring locking to do any update or delete, I fear that even if I were able to work out the correct locks to do what I'm looking for, it would not be scalable and could not handle massive concurrency.

Right now I'm not sure where to go. Is it true that maintaining locks while the row is processed cannot be achieved (even if it did not support high tps or massive concurrency)? What am I missing?

In the hopes that people smarter than me and people more experienced than me can help out, below is the test script I was using. It is switched back to the TOP 1 UPDATE method but I left the other method in, commented out, in case you want to explore that, too.

Paste each of these into a separate session, run session 1, then quickly all the others. In about 50 seconds the test will be over. Look at the Messages from each session to see what work it did (or how it failed). The first session will show a rowset with a snapshot taken once a second detailing the locks present and the being-processed queue items. It works sometimes, and other times doesn't work at all.

**Session 1**

```
/* Session 1: Setup and control - Run this session first, then immediately run all other sessions */
IF Object_ID('dbo.Queue', 'U') IS NULL
   CREATE TABLE dbo.Queue (
      QueueID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
      StatusID int NOT NULL,
      QueuedDate datetime CONSTRAINT DF_Queue_QueuedDate DEFAULT (GetDate()),
      CONSTRAINT PK_Queue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (QueuedDate, QueueID)
   );

IF Object_ID('dbo.QueueHistory', 'U') IS NULL
   CREATE TABLE dbo.QueueHistory (
      HistoryDate datetime NOT NULL,
      QueueID int NOT NULL
   );

IF Object_ID('dbo.LockHistory', 'U') IS NULL
   CREATE TABLE dbo.LockHistory (
      HistoryDate datetime NOT NULL,
      ResourceType varchar(100),
      RequestMode varchar(100),
      RequestStatus varchar(100),
      ResourceDescription varchar(200),
      ResourceAssociatedEntityID varchar(200)
   );

IF Object_ID('dbo.StartTime', 'U') IS NULL
   CREATE TABLE dbo.StartTime (
      StartTime datetime NOT NULL
   );

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM dbo.Queue) < 10000 BEGIN
   TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Queue;

   WITH A (N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
   B (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM A Z, A I, A P),
   C (N) AS (SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM B O, B W)
   INSERT dbo.Queue (StatusID, QueuedDate)
   SELECT 1, DateAdd(millisecond, C.N * 3, GetDate() - '00:05:00')
   FROM C
   WHERE C.N <= 10000;
END;

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.StartTime;
INSERT dbo.StartTime SELECT GetDate() + '00:00:15'; -- or however long it takes you to go run the other sessions
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.QueueHistory;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
   @Time varchar(8),
   @Now datetime;
SELECT @Time = Convert(varchar(8), StartTime, 114)
FROM dbo.StartTime;
WAITFOR TIME @Time;

DECLARE @i int,
@QueueID int;
SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= 33 BEGIN
   SET @Now  = GetDate();
   INSERT dbo.QueueHistory
   SELECT
      @Now,
      QueueID
   FROM
      dbo.Queue Q WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE
      Q.StatusID <> 1;

   INSERT dbo.LockHistory
   SELECT
      @Now,
      L.resource_type,
      L.request_mode,
      L.request_status,
      L.resource_description,
      L.resource_associated_entity_id
   FROM
      sys.dm_tran_current_transaction T
      INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_locks L
         ON L.request_owner_id = T.transaction_id;
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
   SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

WITH Cols AS (
   SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY HistoryDate ORDER BY QueueID) Col
   FROM dbo.QueueHistory
), P AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
      Cols
      PIVOT (Max(QueueID) FOR Col IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8])) P
)
SELECT L.*, P.[1], P.[2], P.[3], P.[4], P.[5], P.[6], P.[7], P.[8]
FROM
   dbo.LockHistory L
   FULL JOIN P
      ON L.HistoryDate = P.HistoryDate

/* Clean up afterward
DROP TABLE dbo.StartTime;
DROP TABLE dbo.LockHistory;
DROP TABLE dbo.QueueHistory;
DROP TABLE dbo.Queue;
*/
```

**Session 2**

```
/* Session 2: Simulate an application instance holding a row locked for a long period, and eventually abandoning it. */
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE
   @QueueID int,
   @Time varchar(8);
SELECT @Time = Convert(varchar(8), StartTime + '0:00:01', 114)
FROM dbo.StartTime;
WAITFOR TIME @Time;
BEGIN TRAN;

--SET @QueueID = (
--   SELECT TOP 1 QueueID
--   FROM dbo.Queue WITH (READPAST, UPDLOCK)
--   WHERE StatusID = 1 -- ready
--   ORDER BY QueuedDate, QueueID
--);

--UPDATE dbo.Queue
--SET StatusID = 2 -- in process
----OUTPUT Inserted.*
--WHERE QueueID = @QueueID;

SET @QueueID = NULL;
UPDATE Q
SET Q.StatusID = 1, @QueueID = Q.QueueID
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 1 *
   FROM dbo.Queue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
   WHERE StatusID = 1
   ORDER BY QueuedDate, QueueID
) Q

PRINT @QueueID;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'; -- Release it partway through the test

ROLLBACK TRAN; -- Simulate client disconnecting
```

**Session 3**

```
/* Session 3: Run a near-continuous series of "failed" queue processing. */
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE
   @QueueID int,
   @EndDate datetime,
   @NextDate datetime,
   @Time varchar(8);

SELECT
   @EndDate = StartTime + '0:00:33',
   @Time = Convert(varchar(8), StartTime, 114)
FROM dbo.StartTime;

WAITFOR TIME @Time;

WHILE GetDate() < @EndDate BEGIN
   BEGIN TRAN;

   --SET @QueueID = (
   --   SELECT TOP 1 QueueID
   --   FROM dbo.Queue WITH (READPAST, UPDLOCK)
   --   WHERE StatusID = 1 -- ready
   --   ORDER BY QueuedDate, QueueID
   --);

   --UPDATE dbo.Queue
   --SET StatusID = 2 -- in process
   ----OUTPUT Inserted.*
   --WHERE QueueID = @QueueID;

   SET @QueueID = NULL;
   UPDATE Q
   SET Q.StatusID = 1, @QueueID = Q.QueueID
   FROM (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.Queue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
      WHERE StatusID = 1
      ORDER BY QueuedDate, QueueID
   ) Q

   PRINT @QueueID;

   SET @NextDate = GetDate() + '00:00:00.015';
   WHILE GetDate() < @NextDate SET NOCOUNT ON;
   ROLLBACK TRAN;
END
```

**Session 4 and up -- as many as you like**

```
/* Session 4: "Process" the queue normally, one every second for 30 seconds. */
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Time varchar(8);
SELECT @Time = Convert(varchar(8), StartTime, 114)
FROM dbo.StartTime;
WAITFOR TIME @Time;

DECLARE @i int,
@QueueID int;
SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= 30 BEGIN
   BEGIN TRAN;

   --SET @QueueID = (
   --   SELECT TOP 1 QueueID
   --   FROM dbo.Queue WITH (READPAST, UPDLOCK)
   --   WHERE StatusID = 1 -- ready
   --   ORDER BY QueuedDate, QueueID
   --);

   --UPDATE dbo.Queue
   --SET StatusID = 2 -- in process
   --WHERE QueueID = @QueueID;

   SET @QueueID = NULL;
   UPDATE Q
   SET Q.StatusID = 1, @QueueID = Q.QueueID
   FROM (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.Queue WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
      WHERE StatusID = 1
      ORDER BY QueuedDate, QueueID
   ) Q

   PRINT @QueueID;
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
   SET @i = @i + 1;
   DELETE dbo.Queue
   WHERE QueueID = @QueueID;   
   COMMIT TRAN;
END
```

Comment: The queues as described in the article linked can scale to hundreds or lower thousands of operations per second. The hot spot contention issues are only relevant at higher scale. There are known mitigation strategies that can achieve higher throughput on high end system, going into tens of thousands per second, but those mitigations need careful evaluation and are deployed under [SQLCAT](http://sqlcat.com/) supervision.

Comment: One interesting wrinkle is that with `READPAST, UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK` my script for capturing data into the QueueHistory table is doing nothing. I wonder if that's because the StatusID is not committed? It's using `WITH (NOLOCK)` so theoretically should work... and it did work before! I'm not sure why it's not working now, but it's probably another learning experience.

Comment: Could you reduce your code to the smallest sample that exhibits the deadlocking and other problems you are trying to resolve?

Comment: @Nick I'll try to reduce the code. About your other comments, there is an identity column that is part of the clustered index and ordered by after the date. I am quite willing to entertain a "destructive read" (DELETE with OUTPUT) but one of the asked-for requirements was, in the case of an application instance failing, for the row to return to processing automatically. So my question here is whether that is possible.

Comment: Try the destructive read approach and place dequeued items in a separate table from where they may be re-enqueued if necessary. If that fixes it, then you can invest in making this re-enqueue process work smoothly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need *exactly* 3 [lock hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

- READPAST
- UPDLOCK
- ROWLOCK

I answered this previously on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001

As Remus says, using service broker is *nicer* but these hints do work

Your error about isolation level usually means replication or NOLOCK is involved.

Comment: Using those hints on my script as given above yields deadlocks and processes out of order. (`UPDATE SET ... FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM ... ORDER BY ...)`) Does this mean that my UPDATE pattern with holding a lock cannot work? Also, the moment you combine `READPAST` with `HOLDLOCK` you get the error. There is no replication on this server and the isolation level is READ COMMITTED.

Comment: @ErikE - Just as important as how you query the table is how the table is structured.  The table you are using as a queue must be **clustered in the dequeue order such that the next item to be dequeued is unambiguous**. This is critical. Skimming your code above, I don't see any clustered indexes defined.

Comment: @Nick that makes perfectly eminent sense and I don't know why I didn't think of it. I added the proper PK constraint (and updated my script above), and still got deadlocks. However, the items were now processed in the right order, barring the repeat processing for the deadlocked items.

Comment: @ErikE - 1. Your queue should only contain queued items. Dequeuing and item should mean deleting it from the queue table. I see that you are instead updating the `StatusID` to dequeue an item. Is that correct? 2. Your dequeue order must be unambiguous. If you are queueing items by `GETDATE()`, then at high volumes it is very likely that multiple items will be equally eligible for dequeuing at the same time. This will lead to deadlocks. I suggest adding an `IDENTITY` to the clustered index to guarantee an unambiguous dequeue order.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server works great for storing relational data. As for a job queue, it's not so great. See this article that is written for MySQL but it can also apply here. https://blog.engineyard.com/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you

Comment: Thanks, Eric. In my original reply to the question, I was suggesting to use SQL Server Service Broker because I know for a fact that the table-as-queue method is not really what the database was made for. But I think that is not a good recommendation any more because SB is really just for messages. The ACID properties of data put in the database make it a very attractive container to try to (ab)use. Can you suggest an alternate, low-cost product that will function well as a generic queue? And can be backed up, etc. etc.?

Comment: The article is guilty of a known fallacy in queue processing: combine state and events into a single table (actually if you look at the article comments you'll see I had objected this some time ago). The typical symptom of this problem is the 'processed/processing' field. Combining the state with the events (ie. making the state table the 'queue') results in growing the 'queue' to huge sizes (since the state table  *is* the queue). Separating events into a true queue leads to a queue that 'drains' (goes empty) and this behaves *much* better.

Comment: Doesn't the article suggest exactly that: the queue table has ONLY items ready for work.?

Comment: @ErikE: you are refering to this paragraph, right? *it’s also really easy to avoid the one-big-table syndrome. Just create a separate table for new emails, and when you’re done processing them, INSERT them into long-term storage and then DELETE them from the queue table. The table of new emails will typically stay very small and operations on it will be fast*. My quarrel with this is that is given as a *workaround* for the issue of 'big queues'. This recommendation should had been in the openning of the article, is a *fundamental* issue.

Comment: If you start thinking in a clear separation of state vs. event then you start vdown a much easier path. Even the recomemendation above would change into *insert new emails into the `emails` table **and** into the `new_emails` queue. Processing polls the `new_emails` queue and updates the state in the `emails` table*. This also avoids the the problem of 'fat' state traveling in queues. *If* we would talk about distributed processing and *true* queues, with communication, (eg. SSB) then things get more compplicate as shared state is problematic in distirbuted systems.

Comment: @Remus I was thinking exactly along those lines, that inserting to *both* tables might make more sense than inserting to one and having to move it.