# How should I configure a table to optimize for frequent inserts and deletes?

Tags: sql-server, table, queue

- I know about making the clustered index a steadily increment field, like a `datetime` field. So that will give me fast inserts.

However, the deletes will be based on a consumer of the "queue". So the table looks roughly like this.

```
 CREATE TABLE wk.WorkQueue
    ( TimePosted datetime2    NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT DF_WorkQueue_TimePosted DEFAULT( sysdatetime())
    , Producer   varchar(64)  NOT NULL 
    , Consumer   varchar(64)  NOT NULL
    , WorkData   varchar(800)     NULL -- simple model
    , CONSTRAINT PK_WorkQueue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( TimePosted ASC ) ON [INDEX]
    , INDEX IX_WorkQueue_by_QueuedForConsumer NONCLUSTERED 
        ( Consumer   ASC 
        , TimePosted ASC
        )
      ON [INDEX]
     )
     ON [PRIMARY]
     ;
```

What's the best way to structure the table to frequently delete data from the table.

I'm usually doing this to pull from the table:

```
DELETE wk.WorkQueue
OUTPUT deleted.TimePosted, deleted.Producer, deleted.WorkData  
  INTO @tWork ( TimePosted, Producer, WorkData )
  FROM wk.WorkQueue WITH (INDEX(IX_WorkQueue_by_QueuedForConsumer))
 WHERE Consumer = @WorkerName
;
```

Is there a good way to set up the second index, to make quick deletes? Should I use `WITH(ROWLOCK)`?

Comment: See http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/ and https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20399 and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/

Comment: In addition you could partition the table on Consumer, and add Consumer to the PK, so each Consumer has a dedicated partition.  And then you wouldn't need the other index.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks for the pointers, they added some advice to whatever I implement.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I'm using 2014, so my understanding is that table partitioning doesn't exist there (not a dba). Would it be stable to just do this thing in CLR? I've been experimenting some with light CLR, but I'm afraid--so far--to do too much with it. Like I have some proprietary .net wrapper dlls that will write transact with disk queues.

Comment: Partitioning is in SQL 2014, but only in Enterprise Edition.  In SQL 2016 SP1 and later, it's in every edition.